# Как решить проблему с частотным ограничением в VK Api?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Частотное ограничение ВК - 3 метода в секунду.
Мне же нужно послать 100 методов. 
(Чтобы получить ID'ы пользователей лайкнувших последнее 100 постов).
Как лучше всего избежать ограничения?

Пробовал sleep(1) в цикле, но страница долго грузит и просто не отвечает в итоге.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ограничение выставляется для токена. То есть, 3 запроса в секунду - это с одного vk-приложения. Соответственно, обойти ограничение программно нельзя.
Обойти ограничение можно, делая запросы с нескольких vk-приложений, получив действующие токены для каждого, и запуская свой скрипт для каждого токена так, что один, например, будет собирать с 1 по 10, второй с 11 по 20 и т.д.. Это тоже можно автоматизировать, можно использовать потоки, но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: А как можно реализовать это через потоки?

Comment: Смотрите расширение PThreads

Comment: Мне нужно просто передать исполнение скрипта на фон с некоторым интервалом, чтобы в браузере не выдавалась ошибка из-за ограничения в 30 секунд на ответ страницы

Comment: Тогда можете запускать скрипт через командную строку. `php /path/to/script.php`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод [`execute`](https://vk.com/dev/execute).
 Он позволяет совершить до 25 обращений к разным методам в рамках одного запроса.

Comment: мне нужно к одному методу, а не к разным

Comment: @CoffeeinTime можно и к одному.